# solr sanitizing query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I am using solr with ruby on rails.
It's all working well, I just need to know if there's any existing code to sanitize user input, like a query starting with ? or *

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know any code that does this, but theoretically it could be done by looking at the [parsing code in Lucene](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/queryparser/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.java) and searching for `throw new ParseException` (only 16 matches!).

In practice, I think you're better off just catching any solr exceptions in your code and showing an "invalid query" message or something like that.

**EDIT:** Here are a couple of "sanitizers":

- http://pivotallabs.com/users/zach/blog/articles/937-sanitizing-solr-requests
- http://github.com/jvoorhis/lucene_query
- http://e-mats.org/2010/01/escaping-characters-in-a-solr-query-solr-url/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) with PHP then you can use the `Solarium_Escape::term()` method.

```
/**
 * Escape a term
 *
 * A term is a single word.
 * All characters that have a special meaning in a Solr query are escaped.
 *
 * If you want to use the input as a phrase please use the {@link phrase()}
 * method, because a phrase requires much less escaping.\
 *
 * @link http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters
 *
 * @param string $input
 * @return string
 */
static public function term($input)
{
    $pattern = '/(\+|-|&&|\|\||!|\(|\)|\{|}|\[|]|\^|"|~|\*|\?|:|\\\)/';

    return preg_replace($pattern, '\\\$1', $input);
}
```