# How do I escape illegal characters in a sunspot/solr fulltext search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr, sunspot

I have a sunspot/solr setup for fulltext searching model attributes.  My QA just searched on " and +, both of which caused a 500 error:

Solr Response: `orgapachelucenequeryParserParseException_Cannot_parse__Encountered_EOF_at_line_1_column_0_Was_expecting_one_of_____NOT______________________________QUOTED______TERM______PREFIXTERM______WILDTERM__________________NUMBER______TERM____________`

How can I make these query strings safe?  Is there a method in Sunspot to handle this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [solr sanitizing query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133573/solr-sanitizing-query)

Answer (score 5):

There is no method in Sunspot to filter those, because they are valid in certain kinds of Lucene queries. Sunspot is using the [DisMax Query Parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#Query_Syntax) by default, so you can read its documentation to learn more about those characters.

> [[DisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#Query_Syntax)] is designed to be support raw input strings provided by users with no special escaping. '+' and '-' characters are treated as "mandatory" and "prohibited" modifiers for the subsequent terms. Text wrapped in balanced quote characters '"' are treated as phrases […]

If you intend to never use those characters, you can filter them yourself from queries(the back slash is to escape minus sign).

```
Post.search do
  keywords params[:q].gsub(/[+\-"]/,'')
end
```

You may want to wrap that in a controller method, if you're invoking Sunspot's `search` method within a controller, or a model method if you're calling Sunspot's `solr_search` method from within your class's own custom `search` method.

Comment: I'd love to take credit for this code, but a wiser, smarter person passed it on to me:
`"abc+-/def".gsub(/[+\-"\/]/) { |c| "\\" + c } # outputs => abc\+\-\/def`
This will actually escape the characters in case you are actually trying to use these characters in a search with Solr.