# Any way to compose Solr queries as POSTs in XML,JSON?

Tags: solr

I already use UpdateJSON to add documents to the index and updating/deleting them. It definitely beats writing the XML body in the request URL.

Is there any way to compose queries and POST them to Solr instead of using the GET URL. I am worried about giving long and complex query strings:

- it will get too long that Tomcat may reject it
- escaping special characters for both HTTP and Solr
- some user-supplied strings may break the query (yes I read [solr sanitizing query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133573/solr-sanitizing-query))
- managing a set of textual queries gets unmanageable in python

of course, managing these issues is trivial in my testing system, but I am worried about production systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just switch from GET to POST and it just works.

I wouldn't do it by default however:

- You lose web server logging
- GET is more appropriate than POST for queries because of its safe semantics
- You lose HTTP caching

Comment: Wont Solr's cache still help if HTTP caches are not possible? How much of a loss is that? Im too novice to diagnose by logging the application server. What problems will I miss? Please elaborate on "safe semantics".

Comment: @aitchnyu: yes, Solr caches still apply. For information on Solr and HTTP caching see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAndHTTPCaches

Comment: @aitchnyu: about safe methods, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html