# Matching a Forward Slash with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't have much experience with JavaScript but i'm trying to create a tag system which, instead of using `@` or `#`, would use `/`.

```
var start = /#/ig; // @ Match

var word = /#(\w+)/ig; //@abc Match
```

How could I use a `/` instead of the `#`. I've tried doing `var slash = '/'` and adding `+ slash +`, but that failed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177767/178816

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can escape it like this.

```
/\//ig; //  Matches /
```

or just use indexOf

```
if(str.indexOf("/") > -1)
```

Comment: Thank you Ben, I tried that as well but I added another \ at the end.

Comment: I see some people putting "/" at start and end of RegEx and other don't. I didn't understand usage of "/" , can you please clarify

Answer (score 38):

You need to escape the `/` with a `\`.

```
/\//ig // matches /
```

Answer (score 20):

You can escape it by preceding it with a `\` (making it `\/`), or you could use `new RegExp('/')` to [avoid escaping the regex](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping#a-slash).

See [example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcavazos/3wmpnc8j/).

```js
'/'.match(/\//)            // matches /
'/'.match(new RegExp('/')  // matches /
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use `/` you need to escape it with a `\`

```
var word = /\/(\w+)/ig;
```

Answer (score 9):

In regular expressions, "/" is a special character which needs to be escaped (AKA flagged by placing a \ before it thus negating any specialized function it might serve).

Here's what you need:

```
var word = /\/(\w+)/ig; //   /abc Match
```

Read up on RegEx special characters here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: "/" is not a special character in regular expressions. It is however a special character in JavaScript that delimits where the regex starts and ends.

Answer (score 7):

You can also work around special JS handling of the forward slash by enclosing it in a character group, like so:

```
const start = /[/]/g;
"/dev/null".match(start)     // => ["/", "/"]

const word = /[/](\w+)/ig;
"/dev/null".match(word)      // => ["/dev", "/null"]
```

Comment: +1, Using a character set to avoid escaping does make the RegEx one character longer, but it's worth it for readability: `/[/]/` visually differentiates the trailing delimiter more clearly than `/\//`.

Comment: `/[/]/` is easier to read and works, but unfortunately, some RegEx validators will report **"An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash"** even within a *character group*.  So, I've switched back to the ugly `/\//` form.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered two issues related to the foregoing, when extracting text delimited by `\` and `/`, and found a solution that fits both, other than using `new RegExp`, which requires `\\\\` at the start.  These findings are in Chrome and IE11.

The regular expression

```
/\\(.*)\//g
```

does not work.  I think the `//` is interpreted as the start of a comment in spite of the escape character.  The regular expression (equally valid in my case though not in general)

```
/\b/\\(.*)\/\b/g
```

does not work either.  I think the second `/` terminates the regular expression in spite of the escape character.

What does work for me is to represent `/` as `\x2F`, which is the hexadecimal representation of `/`.  I think that's more efficient and understandable than using `new RegExp`, but of course it needs a comment to identify the hex code.

Answer (score 0):

Forward Slash is special character so,you have to add a backslash before forward slash to make it work

```
$patterm = "/[0-9]{2}+(?:-|.|\/)+[a-zA-Z]{3}+(?:-|.|\/)+[0-9]{4}/";
```

where  / represents search for /
In this way you

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to match on the `/` in a date in C#.  I did it just by using `(\/)`:

```
string pattern = "([0-9])([0-9])?(\/)([0-9])([0-9])?(\/)(\d{4})";
string text = "Start Date: 4/1/2018";

Match m = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

if (m.Success) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);  // 4/1/2018
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Found!");
}
```

JavaScript should also be able to similarly use `(\/)`.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?  This works and I have proven that through testing it.

Comment: I think it was an accident, sorry. I tried to undo it, but it says my vote is locked unless the answer is edited. The only thing I see is that you have a log of capturing groups that you don't seem to be using. Any reason why everything is in parenthesis?

Comment: @RyanQuinn Thanks for the explanation. I used parentheticals to group things together to represent a particular digit I was expecting. It also seemed to require them on a site I was using to test it out:  https://regexr.com  I edited my post (just added a space at the end), so you should be able to remove the downvote if you wish.