# Regex matching partial url

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to compose a regex for a partial url path. The path looks something like:

```
/stoic/variable/important/
```

By "stoic" I mean that part is stoic and has the same letters that won't change. By "variable" I mean that part is dynamic and will change dependent on some stuff, and should be an alphanumeric combination. By "important" I mean a part that is just composed of letters that I want to capture precisely.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
/^(/stoic/\w+\/important/)$/.test(someString)
```

Comment: `/stoic/\w+\/important/` escape all `/` here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching a Forward Slash with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657152/matching-a-forward-slash-with-a-regex)

Comment: yeah I forgot to escape the /, for any future reference, the solution is: `/^(\/stoic\/\w+\/important\/)$/`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to escaping all the slashes, you can also use the RegExp constructor:

```
RegExp('^(/stoic/\\w+/important/)$').test('/stoic/foobar/important/')
// => true
```

Note that you need to use two backslashes for the character classes then, as single backslashes will only trigger the string escapes such as `'\n'`.