# Replace './' dot slash globally with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all instances of `./` in my js

My code is like this

```
var text = './test';
var baseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/';
text = text.replace(/./\/g, baseUrl);
```

This isn't working as I want to also replace a forward slash. How can I ignore this?

Comment: `/./\/g` =>  `/\.\//g`

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work, because I also want to replace the `.`. @WiktorStribiżew this works

Comment: `.` in regex means *any character* so you need to escape it to match the literal dot

Comment: Should this question have been edited rather than closed? Although the title suggested a duplicate, the problem was actually matching `./` rather than just `/`

Comment: personally I don't think it should be closed. I couldn't find the answer to this and would consider it to be a relatively common issue - but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @peterflanagan can you define removing forward slash globally?, you mean the last forward slash from url as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to match the [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) like `\.` and the forward slash like `\/`:

If you want to match a literal dot you have to escape it using a backslash or else it would match [(Almost) Any Character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

You have to [escape the forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657152/matching-a-forward-slash-with-a-regex) `\/` because  that is the delimiter used for the start and the end of the regex.

```js
var text = './test';
var baseUrl = 'http://www.example.com/';
text = text.replace(/\.\//g, baseUrl);
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Maybe explain about escaping and why both '.' and '/' need to be escaped?

Comment: @brabster I have updated my answer.