# Lucene queryparser with "/" in query criteria

Tags: lucene, query-parser

When I try to search for something such as "workaround/fix" within Lucene, it throws this error:

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse 'workaround/fix': Lexical error at line 1, column 15.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/fix"
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:131)
    at pi.lucengine.LucIndex.main(LucIndex.java:112)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 15.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/fix"
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserTokenManager.getNextToken(QueryParserTokenManager.java:1133)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_scan_token(QueryParser.java:599)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_3R_2(QueryParser.java:482)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_3_1(QueryParser.java:489)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_2_1(QueryParser.java:475)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:226)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:181)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:121)
```

This are my lines 111 and 112:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, field, analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse(newLine);
```

What do I need to do to allow it to parse the "/"?

Answer (score 21):

The query parser interprets slashes as the beginning/end or a regex query (as of 4.0, see [documentation here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Regexp_Searches)).

So, to incorporate slashes into the query, you will need to [escape them](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters) by adding a backslash (`\`) before them.

You can handle escaping with [`QueryParser.escape(String)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem when using '/' in lucene queries issued from the elastic search kibana dashboard. I was escaping the '/' characters as indicated in the documentation and still not getting any success. I think this is related to the template bug reported here : https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/789. Not sure yet, will update when we update the logstash components

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where when using forward slash with wildcard it just wouldn't return any result, even if escaped it:

```
+(*16/17*)
+(*16\/17*)
```

The solution was to add double quote:

```
+("*16/17*")
+("*16\/17*")
```

Comment: It worked for me.         "xxxxtestxxxx"

final Query query = queryParser.parse("\"*/test*\"");