# How to get Solr to tokenize forward slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, hydra

Custom identifiers on my `Rails` objects include forward slashes. For example an identifier might look like `ncsu.edu/123456789`. When I try to query Solr for that identifier I'm getting back any result that has `ncsu.edu` in it. The metadata for the Rails object is below:

```
class IntellectualObjectMetadata < ActiveFedora::RdfxmlRDFDatastream
  map_predicates do |map|
    map.intellectual_object_identifier(in: RDF::DC, to: 'identifier') do |index|
      index.as :stored_searchable
    end
  end
end
```

And I'm querying like so:

```
IntellectualObject.where(desc_metadata__intellectual_object_identifier_tesim: params[:intellectual_object_identifier]).first
```

I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to tokenize the Solr query so it returns only objects that match the whole identifier instead of partial matches. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226762/solr-query-not-parsing-forward-slash) you can escape it with a backslash when you're searching for it, so in your case:

```
IntellectualObject.where(desc_metadata__intellectual_object_identifier_tesim: params[:intellectual_object_identifier].gsub("/","\/")).first
```

note the `gsub` to sub your `/` for `\/`

EDIT: as you can see in the documentation [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax):

Solr 4.0 added regular expression support, which means that '/' is now a special character and must be escaped if searching for literal forward slash.

so if you have a token saved like `aaa/bbb` you search for it with `aaa\/bbb`

EDIT #2: from [the lucene docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) which are linked to above.

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

`+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`

Comment: That doesn't actually work because the identifier stored in Solr still has the "\" in it. It doesn't matter how I pass the parameter in, what matters is how the identifier is stored.

Comment: See [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) if you have `aaa/bbb` stored in your database you need to search for it with `aaa\/bbb`

Comment: also, why do you have a backslash in your identifier? in the example you gave it was `ncsu.edu/123456789`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant "/".

Comment: Do you also need to escape periods?

Comment: doesn't look like it.

Comment: Okay, well I tried adding the gsub and it still returns anything that matches the `ncsu.edu` part. Didn't change anything.

Comment: ok, well I'm not sure what else you're doing wrong, but that's the query syntax.