# Can you modify character escaping in spring-data-solr?

Tags: spring-data-solr

We store a path in our schema, slash-delimited, and it also starts with a slash. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550603/2991106) solr interprets slashes in the beginning of queries as regex expressions after version 4.0, which means that we need to escape the slash.

But [SolrTemplate.queryForPage(Query, Class)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/SolrTemplate.html#queryForPage%28org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Query,%20java.lang.Class%29) does not escape the slash, so the natural solution is to use QueryParser.escape(searchTerm) suggested in the link above.

However, this will add a backslashe to escape the slash, and that backslash will be escaped by SolrTemplate, resulting in an escaped backslash in the query - which gives no results

I'll add a couple of examples for clarity:

Query without any escaping:

```
q=paths:/myrootpath&start=0&rows=10
```

Query with manual escaping of the slash([QueryParser.escape(String)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape%28java.lang.String%29)):

```
q=paths:\\/myrootpath&start=0&rows=10
```

The query I need:

```
q=paths:\/myrootpath&start=0&rows=10
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended, since as far as I know, pre-4.0-solr didn't need to escape slashes

So is there way in spring-data-solr to either disable character escaping for a query, or modify which characters that are escaped?

Comment: @tlavarea I'm sorry, but I did not find a solution, but it might be possible in later versions, it's been almost a year since I worked on that proejct. Anyway, I figured it must be a bug. As a workaround I transformed the slash to/from a semi-colon

Comment: That's a good solution. I base64 encoded my paths then wrote a custom solr converter to decode/encode as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I like idea with converter. We can add new class ContentPath:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
public class ContentPath {
    private String path;
}
```

Then new converter needs to be registered while SolrTemplate creation:

```
SolrTemplate solrTemplate = ...
DefaultQueryParser defaultQueryParser = new DefaultQueryParser();
defaultQueryParser.registerConverter(new Converter<ContentPath, String>() {

    @Override
    public String convert(ContentPath o) {
        return escape(o.getPath());
    }

});
solrTemplate.registerQueryParser(Query.class, defaultQueryParser);
```

Last change needs to be done while query definition:

```
new SimpleQuery((new Criteria(IDENTIFIER)).is(new ContentPath(id)));
```