# how to query string containing forward slash in Solr

Tags: solr

I need to query a database of products, the query can contains forward slash like "30/20", but it always splits the query in two parts as 
_text: 30 and _text: 20.

I tried to escape the forward slash with a back slash like this "30/20" or to use encodeURI as "30%2F20" but it does not work either.

Shall I encode/replace the forward slash in the database?

I tried with quotes following ([Solr Query not parsing forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226762/solr-query-not-parsing-forward-slash)) like "5/12" in the query field, it's not working if I have "12.5/12" in the database.

Anyone had the issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a different tokenizer that doesn't split on `/`, such as [the WhitespaceTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-WhiteSpaceTokenizer). That way `5/12` will be kept as one, single token.

If you still need to support people querying for `5 12` to give a hit as well, that would be served by the original field type. If you need to support querying by a subset of the complete token as well (i.e. `5/12` when the value is `12.5/12`), use an NGramFilter to split the token further into subtokens covering every combination (`1`, `12`, `12.5`, etc.).