# Solr/Lucene Query Validation

Tags: solr, tdd

Does anyone have a regex that can be used to validate that a query to be sent to lucene is is well formatted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [solr sanitizing query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133573/solr-sanitizing-query)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/praized/lucene-query-validator/blob/master/src/luceneQueryValidator.js

This is a JavaScript attempt.  I have not verified it's success but from reviewing the code, everything looks legit.

If you're allowing your users to enter in free text, there is always the chance that they'll mistype a field name (i.e. naem:Bob instead of name:Bob ).  This validator will not catch issues like that.

Comment: I was going to use the validator for unit testing our query builders.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a js AMD module here: https://github.com/grahamscott/lucene-validator-amd-module

It's based on the praized module above, but is easier to integrate client-side, and doesn't rely on window.alert()